# Merge Lists with Python

Tags: python, list

If I had two lists like these

```
["John", "Jim", "Jimmy"]

["100", "200", "300"]
```

How would I be able to merge the lists so that the first item in each list matches up with the other first item and so on like this

```
["John100", "Jim200", "Jimmy300"]
```

Comment: have you tried `zip()`?

Comment: ```["".join(elem) for elem in zip(first_list, second_list)]```

Comment: l1 = ["John", "Jim", "Jimmy"]; 
l2 = ["100", "200", "300"]; 
l3 = [i+j for (i,j) in zip(l1,l2)];
print(l3);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `zip()` for this:

```py
list1 = ["John", "Jim", "Jimmy"]
list2 = ["100", "200", "300"]

merged = [l1 + l2 for l1, l2 in zip(list1, list2)]

print(merged)
```

Output:

```py
['John100', 'Jim200', 'Jimmy300']
```